# Change the color of AutoComplPop

Tags: vim

Is there a way to change the background color of the drop down for AutoComplPop(A plug-in for vim)?

Right now this is what my setup looks like:

[image]

I would like to change the pink background to something a little more easy on the eyes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
" vanilla Vim
hi Pmenu ctermbg=color

" Vim with GUI support
hi Pmenu guibg=color
```

Pmenu is the popup menu.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to background color in the popup menu, you may also want to change selection background color, e.g., in your snapshot, the lightyellow bar on "newFile".

This can be done via the following commands, for example,

> " you may change 'cterm' below into 'gui' if working with GUI
>   :hi PmenuSel   ctermbg=red

where the postfix 'bg' means 'background'.

Similarly, 
the 'foreground' color can also be modified via, say,

> :hi PmenuSel   ctermfg=green

which changes the color of the text you're selecting in the menu into green.